# $.ready not firing

Tags: jquery

I know this question is out there a number of times, but they each look a little different than this. Below is literally the file I am running on apache.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  hello 

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $.ready(function() {
    $("body").append("world");
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please take a look at http://jsperf.com/document-ready-vs-fn-ready-pointless-optimizations-ftw/2 before responding to this question.

Comment: If I change "$.ready" to "$().ready" everything works fine.

Comment: @kalisjoshua Change `$.ready` to just `$`... so, `$(function () { ... });`

Comment: I am trying to use this form because of this perf: http://jsperf.com/document-ready-vs-fn-ready-pointless-optimizations-ftw/2

Comment: Since it's causing you problems, I would ignore that jsperf in favor of what jQuery.com actually recommends.

Comment: Even if that was correct call what's the difference? Ready is called once per page so measuring performance in multiple calls doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I'd also ignore that perf on the basis that it's saving like a tenth of a microsecond. This is a great example of premature optimization gone wrong.

Comment: New ways of doing things are never found by those who just follow the path. Sorry if I offended anyone by not properly stating what I was looking for. What is the most optimal way of calling .ready. Just because the gains are small does not mean they are nil.

Comment: `"Sorry if I offended anyone by not properly stating what I was looking for."`... You stated **exactly** what you were looking for in your title - a way to solve your `ready` callback not firing...

Comment: They are effectively nil. The most optimal way of calling .ready is the way that jQuery recommends, as that's the one you can count on continuing to work. Focusing on useless optimizations means you're wasting time that could be spent finding new things that are actually useful.

Comment: jsperf measures _speed_ of code, not correctness.  [`$.noop`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/) will run even faster than `$.ready`, but since it doesn't do what you want, it is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jsPerf case is flawed. `$.ready` is called internally *when the DOM is actually ready*. It will run the functions that were passed to `$(document).ready`. So, it doesn't make sense to call it yourself:

- It's an internal function
- It doesn't wait for the DOM to be ready
- It doesn't accept a function

Just use the normal function `$(...)` or `$(document).ready(...)` as that's what you're looking for (`$.ready` is *not* an alternative as the jsPerf suggests).

Comment: Not surprised that the perf is incorrect. Could you correct it? So then $.fn.ready would be a more performant way to call ready.

Comment: @kalisjoshua: Not quite. Looking at the stats, you can see that on Chrome 20, `$(...)` can be called 800.000 times a second and `$.fn.ready` 1.200.000 times a second. Assuming you only call it a few times, you shouldn't care.

Comment: @kalisjoshua: I understand your interest in optimization, but I don't think you can apply it here. There are differences between browsers, and whereas this month a browser may execute way #1 faster than way #2, it can be the other way round next month in an updated version of the browser.

Answer (score 7):

It should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: Sorry, but no it shouldn't. Please see the jsPerf above.

Comment: You're deliberately ignoring the jQuery documentation in favor of what you think will be faster. That's not the same thing as "should".

Comment: See my comment above "New ways..."

Answer (score 3):

> Please take a look at http://jsperf.com/document-ready-vs-fn-ready-pointless-optimizations-ftw/2 before responding to this question.

There's a reason that page is titled "pointless optimizations".

Instead of making a meaningless optimization - in this case you're shaving off a microsecond or less per pageview - just use the documented methods of running code on document ready.

The answer here is use the normal ways, and go Google "premature optimization".

Comment: Chances are, the amount of time you've spent on this - researching, coding, troubleshooting, posting to SO, commenting - is more time than your optimization would've saved across **billions of pageviews**.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ready` is not an utility function, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("world");
});
```

Comment: I have used the form I posted above in other projects. I don't know why it isn't working in this simple example.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to the `document.ready` callback is -

```
$(function(){

});
```

I like this one because it is easy to remember and is unique enough to stand out when you are reviewing your code.

---

From the jQuery documentation on the `ready()` function -

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code.

So to explain the original syntax - `$('document').ready(function() { ... }` what you are doing is attaching a `ready` callback function to the `document` object so that you'll know when all of the DOM is loaded plus your jQuery libraries.

Comment: -1 This is actually the least performant way of calling this functionality.

Comment: You question was dealing with your ready function not firing - my answer solves this - if you want to talk about optimization then you should make a post about **that**.  You don't downvote answers *after* you change your original question... `-1` to **you** my friend :P

Comment: By "least performant" you mean "adds 1-2% of time to an operation that needs to be run once and can be run roughly a million times a second"?

Answer (score 2):

move your script oout of the body tag and see if that makes a difference.. not sure if that could be the reason..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  hello 

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
<script>
  $.ready(function() {
    $("body").append("world");
  });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 Good thought but not in this case. I did what you suggested but to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
$(function () {
  $('body').append('world');
});
```

Comment: Yes - you are correct - but the `.append('body')` command you gave as an example might be slightly confusing as you are appending the string `'body'` to an element with the selector `'body'`...

Comment: Correct I am appending a string to the body of the document. This is not production code, merely a test page to start off some development. The problem is that the function $.ready (which does exist) isn't firing for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I updated my answer to match the op's snippet.